# Is it possible to Link to Excel File Based on Dynamic Mail Merge Field?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010, mail-merge

If I were to create an excel sheet with merge fields for a Mail Merge, and one of those fields were to be a file location, for example, can I then create a [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/link-or-embed-an-excel-worksheet-HA010120810.aspx#BM4) in my Word document to a **second** Excel file based on the file name / location in the Mail Merge field?

Links pointing to documentation on this subject are equally appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a Hyperlink into the Word document in the normal way and set the display text to whatever you want.

Highlight the hyperlink and use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to see the field code.

```
{HYPERLINK "C:\\path\\to\\excelfile.xls"}
```

Replace the part in quotes with the merge field name.

```
{HYPERLINK "«Link_Path»"}
```

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to switch back to normal view.

Comment: Right on! Actually {LINK ... } was what I needed (I think), thanks for your input. Now on to understanding the switches ("\a \f 4 \h")....